# call gwt web site running in local host super dev mode from android emulator browser

Tags: android, gwt, android-emulator

I have a gwt web app running in super dev mode on my host where is also running an Android Emulator with my android app running.

I have configured the Emulator to resolve the host name and it works because if I call a servlet of the gwt web app from the android app everything works fine.

If I user the browser of the emulator to open an url of my web app (the client part of my gwt web app) it opens a popup saying:
"*Couldn't load "app" from Super Dev Mode server at http://hostname:9876.
Please make sure this server is ready.*"

The server is up and runnign because the same url works if I call it directly from the host.

I'm using eclipse to run the web app and Android Studio to run the Emulator.